# Pre-programming components for data.table's j argument when grouping

Tags: r, data.table, environment

I have a large data.table which I regularly program with and repeatedly carry out something along the lines of the following:

`d.regionOffice <- d.input[, .(sales = sum(sales)), .(region, office)]`

`d.region <- d.regionOffice[, .(sales = sum(sales)), .(region)]`

I have other variables other than `sales = sum(sales)` which are regularly re-used, often with much longer variable names.

Is there a way I can capture this common construct, and then use in data.table?

I've tried naive things like:

`l.sales <- list(sales = sum(sales))`

But R will give you an error saying "Error: object 'sales' not found". Is there a work-around for this?

Note that I have multiple common summary stats, e.g. `profit = sum(profit)`, `customers = sum(customers)` etc. so a custom function which just requires a `by` argument isn't good enough.

Comment: I don't understand why a custom function that just requires a `by` argument isn't good enough. Maybe you want a custom function that requires a `by` argument and a optional arguments for what columns get summarized? Or maybe it just needs smart defaults based on what columns are present?

Comment: I want it to be as flexible as possible. I don't always want to calculate the "profit" or "sales", but sometimes I need both. Any custom function I make will have to have defaults, or some way of parsing what specific summaries I need. E.g. function(salesInc = FALSE, profit = FALSE, ...). Which is quite a lot of characters to write and isn't *that* clear to read. I'm trying to cut down on the number of characters needed while keeping clarity.

Comment: I'm just trying to better understand your goal. As I understand it, you don't like the idea of `foo(dt, profit)`, where, say, `foo` returns a list `d` containing`region` and `region.office` data tables (still not clear why this is bad?), but you do like `bar = baz(profit = sum(profit)); d.regionOffice <- dt[bar, .(region)]; d.region <- dt[bar, .(region, office)]`?  And you're looking for how to create the `baz` function?

Comment: Yes exactly. To be clearer, the actual column names that I use are of similar length to `gross.written.premium` which is considerably longer than the examples I gave. The reason why I don't like the first function you're suggesting is because I'm normally writing a lot of these sub-sets, on the fly during the day, for lots of intermediate tables. Essentially I'm just trying to come up with a shortcut to writing d.input[, .(gross.written.premium = sum(gross.written.premium), gross.claim.incurred = sum...), .(region, office)] etc... writing d.input[, .(gwp, gci), .(region, office)] is the target

Comment: wide-formatted data is harder to do things programatically (IME). What you could do is reshape your raw data in long form, then write a rollup function that takes the name of the field (e.g., 'sales') as input, and returns the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the OP is looking for a short cut to create aggregates with less typing.

Instead of typing

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(iris)

DT[, .(Sepal.Length = mean(Sepal.Length), Petal.Length = mean(Petal.Length)), by = Species]
```

> ```
>       Species Sepal.Length Petal.Length
> 1:     setosa        5.006        1.462
> 2: versicolor        5.936        4.260
> 3:  virginica        6.588        5.552
> ```

we can write

```
cols <- c("Sepal.Length", "Petal.Length")
DT[, lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols = cols, by = Species]
```

> ```
>       Species Sepal.Length Petal.Length
> 1:     setosa        5.006        1.462
> 2: versicolor        5.936        4.260
> 3:  virginica        6.588        5.552
> ```

For convience, this can be placed in a function:

```
agg <- function(dt, cols, grp, fct = sum) {
  dt[, lapply(.SD, fct), .SDcols = cols, by = grp]
}

agg(DT, cols, "Species", mean)
```

> ```
>       Species Sepal.Length Petal.Length
> 1:     setosa        5.006        1.462
> 2: versicolor        5.936        4.260
> 3:  virginica        6.588        5.552
> ```

```
# using default aggregation function
agg(DT, cols, "Species")
```

> ```
>       Species Sepal.Length Petal.Length
> 1:     setosa        250.3         73.1
> 2: versicolor        296.8        213.0
> 3:  virginica        329.4        277.6
> ```

```
# totals without grouping
agg(DT, cols, , mean)
```

> ```
>    Sepal.Length Petal.Length
> 1:     5.843333        3.758
> ```

Or, with another data.table

```
DT2 <- as.data.table(mtcars, keep.rownames = TRUE)
agg(DT2, c("wt", "hp"), "cyl", sum)
```

> ```
>    cyl     wt   hp
> 1:   6 21.820  856
> 2:   4 25.143  909
> 3:   8 55.989 2929
> ```

```
agg(DT2, c("wt", "hp"), "cyl", length)
```

> ```
>    cyl wt hp
> 1:   6  7  7
> 2:   4 11 11
> 3:   8 14 14
> ```

Comment: Thanks Uwe. It's not *exactly* the solution I was looking for, but it's damn close enough.

Comment: @Shillington Great! As I am curious, what is missing to meet your requirements _exactly_?

Comment: One of the key advantages of syntax for successful packages such as data.table and ggplot is its flexibility and minimalism. Pushing things into a function isn't quite as flexible and minimal as remembering a shortcut for some code. Which is actually a reasonable solution in itself... Code Snippets in RStudio. Should have thought of this before. Thanks again Uwe.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution is to just use code-snippets in R. The original problem was to reduce the amount of repetitive typing, which can be done programamtically using the solution above, or semi-manually with code-snippets in RStudio.

In RStudio go: Tools > Global Options > Code > Edit Snippets (at the bottom)

And then add in a snippet, e.g.

```
snippet gwp
    gross.written.premium = sum(gross.written.premium)
```

Then when you're typing code you can just type `gwp`[tab] which will expand to the full code.